# POST from vuejs to php script in same directory

Tags: php, vue.js

I'm trying to post data from vue to php script which exists in the same folder.
when executing `npm run dev` my vue app start's on port 8080, while my Apache configuration uses port 80. what i want to do is to pass data from my vue app which "lives" in the address `http://localhost:8080` to my script which i can access using the address `http://localhost:80/project_name` .
i tried this app as an example [github.com/0x90kh4n](https://github.com/0x90kh4n) ,and while the app works when i simply clone it, when adding it to my "real world" project where i use webpack,babel,npm etc. i cant access it since the app always send requests to localhost:8080 . tried changing the proxy table like this:

```
proxyTable: {
  '/api' : 'http://localhost:80/project_name'
}
```

but it didn't work, here is my implementation of the code in my (single) vue instance

```
<script>
import Navigation from './components/partials/Navigation.vue'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return{
    name: '',
    surname: '',
    users: []
    }
  },
  created: function() {
    this.fetchData(); // Başlangıçta kayıtları al
  },
  methods: {

    fetchData: function() {

      this.$http.get('/api.php')
        .then(function(response) {

          if (response.body.status == 'ok') {

            let users = this.users;
            response.body.users.map(function(value, key) {
              users.push({name: value.name, surname: value.surname});
            });

          }

        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

    }
  },
  components: {
    Navigation
  }
}
```

in the endpoint there is [this file](https://github.com/0x90kh4n/vuejs-php/blob/master/api/api.php), which i'm not including pieces of code from it here since i believe the problem is my vue part of the story...

Might be worth adding my `/config/index.js` export:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8080,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {
      '/api' : 'http://localhost:80/projedt_name'
    },
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be [`proxy`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-proxy) not `proxyTable`?

Comment: Might just be an oversight but your config files proxyTable data has a typo: `proxyTable: {
   '/api' : 'http://localhost:80/projedt_name'
 },`